# How to stop creating new line no data fetch in array

Tags: php

When I `echo` $cia or $grind, it print all rows the variable have but problem is, there are a blank row in each variable at the end. How do stop creating blank while no data fetch in array.

```
$cia ="";
$grind = "";

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sdata) ){
    if($data["cia"]){
        $cia .= $data["cia"] . "\r\n";
    }
    if($data["grind"]){
        $grind.= $data["grind"] . "\r\n";
    }
}
```

echo $cia;
output:

```
---------------------
|LEAVE EXT UNGLUED  |
---------------------
|1/8 PUFF CV/EXT TOE|
---------------------
|MET PADS BOTH      |
---------------------
|                   |
---------------------
```

Comment: But "\r\n" :  CR + LF is used as a new line character in Windows

Comment: `break` doesn't work here?

Comment: Can you edit post adding output example?

Comment: post edited with output example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) extra characters:

```
$grind = rtrim($grind);
```

All:

```
$cia ="";
$grind = "";

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sdata) ){
    if($data["cia"]){
        $cia .= $data["cia"] . "\r\n";
    }
    if($data["grind"]){
        $grind.= $data["grind"] . "\r\n";
    }
}
$grind = rtrim($grind);
$cia = rtrim($cia);
```

Comment: Funny that the only answer that seems to be correct is downvoted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function for getting desired results

```
if(isset($data["cia"])){
    $cia .= $data["cia"] . "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: same return with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to store the data in the loop and filter it at the end to ensure it's ok before using implode with the new line

```
$output=array();
while( $data = mysql_fetch_array( $sdata ) ){
    if( $data['cia'] ) $output[]=$data['cia'];
    if( $data['grind'] ) $output[]=$data['grind'];
}
$output=array_filter( $output );
$output=implode( PHP_EOL, $output );
echo $output;
```